# Why do generic extension methods get called with the parent type from the parent?

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

Consider the following code:

```
public static class ParentHelper {
   public static string GetTypeString<T>(this T parent) where T : Parent {
      return typeof(T).ToString();
   }
}

public abstract class Parent {
   public string GetMyType(bool withReflection) {
      return withReflection
         ? typeof(ParentHelper)
            .GetMethod("GetTypeString")
            .MakeGenericMethod(GetType()).Invoke(null, new object[] { this }) as string
         : this.GetTypeString();
   }
}

public class Child : Parent {
}

void Main() {
   Child child = new Child();
   child.GetMyType(false).Dump();            // Parent
   ((Parent) child).GetMyType(false).Dump(); // Parent
   child.GetMyType(true).Dump();             // Child
   ((Parent) child).GetMyType(true).Dump();  // Child
}
```

To my surprise, The `GetMyType` method returns different values depending on how it calls `GetTypeString` (see comments in `Main` method).

Is there any way for the `GetTypeString` extension method to work with the *child* class type instead of the parent one, when using the normal `object.ExtensionMethod()` syntax?

Note that this code is the minimum example I could put together--my usage is quite different (not returning the type, but rather an attribute decorating the child class).

Comment: If you want runtime type of parameter `parent` use `parent.GetType()` instead of `typeof(T)`.

Comment: I was *just* figuring that out, but that makes everything harder because I want to use `T` in a further generic call `return CallAnotherMethod<T,  SomeType>`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you'll need to replace the `typeof(T)` with `parent.GetType()`, instead.

They do different things.

Answer (score 2):

`this.GetTypeString();` is compiled into `ParentHelper.GetTypeString<Parent>()` because it is the type passed from `Parent.GetMyType`.

Usual solution - make `Parent` generic of its child (aka curiously recursive template) like:

```
 public abstract class Parent<TChild> where TChild : Parent<TChild>
 {
     public string GetMyType()
     { 
         return ((TChild)this).GetTypeString();
     }
 }
```

Alternatively you can use `GetType()` similar how you construct reflection call, but it give up some compile type safety.